# calling two separate methods in an schedulable class depending on the input/context

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, developer, scheduled-job

I have an schedulable class that does two jobs (in two separate methods). I want to be able to specify which one of the two methods to be called when I schedule the class using class.schedule(). Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is just call different method from the execute implementation. Is this comment enough or you need more details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope by passing parameters through constructor and storing them in global instance variables will work for you. I have tried to explain by a code sample. Please note it is not compiled. Hope this helps.

```
System.schedule('test', '0 47 18 * * ?', new Dummy_Schedulable_Class(new String('methodA')));
```

**Scheduler class**

```
global class Dummy_Schedulable_Class implements Schedulable{

    global String methodName;

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        if(methodName=='methodA'){
            testScheduleClassMethod1();
        }else{
            testScheduleClassMethod2();
        }
    }

    public void testScheduleClassMethod1(){
        //TO DO
    }
    public void testScheduleClassMethod2(){
        //TO DO
    }
    public Dummy_Schedulable_Class ( String mName) {
        methodName = mName;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Saroj. This actually gives me an idea. However, two separate processes may want to create the jobs at the same time, in which case, this solution may not work. I'll need to see if I can make it process dependent.

Comment: @DavidJ No you will not have any concurrency issues..If you have two scheduled jobs running at the same time, the two jobs will have completely different context..I just tried and it is working fine..Let me know if you want to see the code..I can post

Comment: only (limited) downside to to this approach is you have to schedule the jobs via anonymous apex or some other apex - the Force.com UI has no way to schedule an apex class job with constructor args